# SQL tables with different detail level - one containing the sum of the other

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sum, sql-update, ssms

I am trying to build a simple model with tables containing forecast data.

The first I will call **[Year Forecast]** and the second **[Month Forecast]**. Like so:

```
| Year | Forecast |
-------------------
| 2018 |   144000 |
| 2019 |   180000 |
| 2020 |   220000 |
| .... |   ...... |
```

I want the DB to allow manual input in the **[Year Forecast]** for  `[Year] > year(getdate())+2`. So in the example the forecast number of 2020 would have been manually entered as a whole number. (Note that Year would be a unique identifier)

For `[Year] < year(getdate())+2` the table **[Year Forecast]** should take the sum of **[Month Forecast]**. This would be for 2018 and 2019 in this example.

```
| ID | Year | Month | Forecast |
--------------------------------
|  1 | 2018 |     1 |    12000 |
|  2 | 2018 |     2 |    12000 |
|  3 | 2018 |     3 |    12000 |
|  4 | 2018 |     4 |    12000 |
|  5 | 2018 |     5 |    12000 |
|  6 | 2018 |     6 |    12000 |
|  7 | 2018 |     7 |    12000 |
|  8 | 2018 |     8 |    12000 |
|  9 | 2018 |     9 |    12000 |
| 10 | 2018 |    10 |    12000 |
| 11 | 2018 |    11 |    12000 |
| 12 | 2018 |    12 |    12000 |
| 13 | 2019 |     1 |    15000 |
| 14 | 2019 |     2 |    15000 |
| .. | .... | ..... | ........ |
```

Relationship would be straightforward, but I want to define a procedure that takes the sum of Forecast of the related year in **[Month Forecast]** and prohibits manual data input for `[Year] < year(getdate())+2`

I've come quite far in my SQL journey and I know this should be possible but is still a bit above my skill level. How should I go about this?

Comment: The query output and prohibiting certain inputs (inserts) seem to be too different things.  Can you clarify what you want here?  Do you want to aggregate the `[Month Forecast]` table, or something else?

Comment: Hi Tim. Two different thing indeed; 1) Aggregate `[Mont Forecast]` (thanks for the right terminology); 2) prohibit manual input on aggregated data. And actually 3) Allow manual input in the same table where data is aggregated, for records where `year > year(getdate())+2`